# When using MongoStat, how do you correctly format the connection string?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to use MongoStat to monitor my database deployment.  Below is the command I'm using to try and connect:

```
mongostat --uri "mongodb+srv://user:password@subdomain.azure.mongodb.net/admin?replicaSet=project-shard-0&connectTimeoutMS=10000&authSource=admin&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1"
```

This produces the error:

```
error configuring the connector: error parsing options from URI: error parsing uri: URI with srv must not include a port number
```

The connection string format that I'm using does actually work when used with MongoRestore.  But with MongoStat, I get this error.  Does anyone here know how I can properly format this connection string?

Answer (score 0):

`man mongostat` shows this:

```
--uri=<connectionString>
              New in version 3.4.6.

              Specify a resolvable URI connection string (enclose in quotes) to connect to the MongoDB deployment.

                 --uri="mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]"
```

Stands to reason that if you try this command instead, it should work:

```
mongostat --uri="mongodb+srv://user:password@subdomain.azure.mongodb.net/admin?replicaSet=project-shard-0&connectTimeoutMS=10000&authSource=admin&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1"
```